# How to do two events with one button

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to do 2 events with 1 button in my react-native app

This is my code

```
onPress={navigation.getParam('HVentana2')} onPress={(ref) => this._menu.hide()}
```

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: it do only the second event, if i put

`() =>{navigation.getParam('HVentana1'); (ref) => this._menu.hide()}`

don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call to one function that contains what you want:

```
onPress={this.onClick}
```

and create `onClick function:

```
onClick = () => {
    navigation.getParam('HVentana2')
    this._menu.hide()
}
```